# Android BroadcastReceiver inside service: issues

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I am currently trying to create an Activity in Android with the capabilities of communicating with a started `BroadcastReceiver` inside of a service but I can't manage to do it well. I don't really know what the problem could be since (I think) I have followed all necessary steps.

In addition, I have other Activities which can communicate with this `BroadcastReceiver` without any problems. The code that I am using for the one I am having problems with is the following:

Registration of the name of the action in file `ActivityList.java` (Another activity):

```
public static final String ACTION1 = "com.test.ActionOne";
public static final String ACTION2 = "com.test.ActionTwo";
```

Registration of the actions with `IntentFilter` in the file `GestTree.java` which extends a `Service`:

Inside `onCreate()`:

```
IntentFilter filter;
filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction(ActivityList.ACTION1);
filter.addAction(ActivityList.ACTION2);
rec = new Receptor(); // This is a class which extends BroadcastReceiver
registerReceiver(receptor, filter);
```

Inside the function `onReceive()` of the `private class Receptor` of `GestTree.java` which extends `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public final void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(ActivityList.ACTION1)) {
    Log.d(tag, "Test Passed!");
    }
}
```

The definition of the service and the Activity `State3Activity`(the one I want to communicate with the service) in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name="State3Activity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >    
</activity>

<service
     android:name="GestTree"
     android:enabled="true"
     android:label="@string/app_name" >
</service>
```

Code inside `State3Activity.java`:

```
public class State3Activity extends Activity {
Button mButton;
EditText editText_Name;
EditText editText_Desc;
private final String tag = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.state3_layout);
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_myButton);
    editText_Nombre  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Name);
    editText_Descripcion = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_Desc);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(ActivityList.ACTION1);

                    // I have tried with all this combination of lines 
                    // but none of them works
                    //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
                    //intent.setClass(State3Activity.this, GestTree.class);
                    //intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);

                }
            });
}
```

There is where the problem comes. The intent never enters on the `onReceive()` function of the class when I press the button. What am I leaving?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I have improved your question with proper formatting, also last two paragraphs were unnecessary, so I removed them - focus on problem, don't need to write "thanks" etc. You can thank people for help by upvoting their answers or accepting final answer.

Comment: Okay, I am pretty new on this, sorry. @DamianKozlak

Comment: why do you use a `BroadcastReceiver` at all? why dont you talk to your `Service` directly?

Comment: are you defining the broadcast listener inside the  activity class of is a separate java file?

Comment: I have just started to learn Android and this code was provided to me by my teacher. I think the way he wants that I communicate with the service is with the BroadcastReceiver, but is any other way similar to this to do it using the Service? @pskink

Comment: just call `Context#startService`

Comment: The Broadcast listener is inside GestTree.java. It is indeed a private class from it and is called Receptor. @insomniac

Comment: Where should I do it @pskink ?

Comment: Probably some issue with a wrong contex,i don't know,Have you tried the approach where you declare it with intent filters inside AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: in the same place where you call `sendBroadcast`

Comment: I haven't tried but I also have some other actions declared in the same way (dynamically) in other files and they work well when I call the Intent @insomniac

Comment: Check if you have any other broadcast listeners for these same actions and they are not calling AbortBroadcast() in this one

Comment: @pskink It leaves me the error that "#" is not recognised. I have also tried with " . " and doesn't work either..

Comment: just call `startService` instead of `sendBroadcast`

Comment: I have two other Broadcast listeners called the same way and in their own files, but none of them "parses" the action ActivityList.ACTION1 . Could this still be the problem @insomniac ?

Comment: @pskink I am afraid it doesn't reach the onReceive either.. :(

Comment: Read about Services,  i mean the official Service class documentation

Comment: @Alberto what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @pskink sorry !! you were right but since I am just a noob I did startService() of the intent I wanted to sendBroadcast() not the real service! ahhahah Thank you very much !! :)

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: Oh no.. I am afraid the problem is still there.. I saw that the service had started but that's all, it is not reaching the onReceive inside it.. Sorry for being so noob @pskink

Comment: No it is not working yet.. I though it was @ParagKadam

Comment: Remove your broadcast receiver and read Service docs,  read it really,  otherwise you will stay in the same place where you are now

Comment: Can you tell what you are exactly trying to achieve? By this way we would be in a better position to tell you if you should use a `BroadcastReceiver` or a `Service` or both or none.

Comment: The base of the code was not made by me, but what I want to achieve is to have a service always runing on background and enabling a Broadcast listener all the time so as to make petitions to it whenever I need. I don't really know if it is a good way to do this, but I am certain that works if I manage to solve the problem. @ParagKadam

Comment: Okay I have been reading a bit and I have managed to finally solve the problem. It was what @pskink said at the begining, by stating startService() which it was not started before. Nonetheless it had to be done in a different place where I put the sendBroadcast(). For me puting the startService() in the onCreate() of a previous Activity has made it work! Thank you to all of you !

Comment: No,  no,  no,  you are still using BroadcastReceiver,  remove it and just call startService whenever you need it

Comment: I know @pskink, but I think I have to leave this BroadcastReceiver since the App was made with it and my teacher just removed some parts which I have to fill now. I don't know whether is a good way to do this but I am convinced that it works since he did it like that. Do you think it will appear any other problem in the future related to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure your service started? If you have not start the service, the method of `onCreate()` will not be executed, and the receiver will not be registed.

Comment: Okay, yes, that was it Lauren! I had to start the service in a different place where I did the sendBroadcast ! Thank you very much